# LINQ: Nested Sorting / Ordering with Boolean Values

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Given the following situation:

```
public class Data {
    public bool Value1 { get; set; }
    public bool Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<Data> {
    new Data { Value1 = true, Value2 = false, Value3 = 5}, // d1
    new Data { Value1 = true, Value2 = true, Value3 = 10}, // d2
    new Data { Value1 = false, Value2 = false, Value3 = 20}, // d3
    new Data { Value1 = false, Value2 = true, Value3 = 30}, // d4
    new Data { Value1 = false, Value2 = false, Value3 = 15} // d5
};

var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value1).ThenByDescending(d => d.Value2).ThenBy(d => d.Value3);
```

What I would like to achieve is: `d1 - d2 - d4 - d5 - d3`

The actual result in `orderedList` is: `d2 - d1 - d4 - d5 - d3`

Which is because on `d2`, `Value2` *and* `Value1` are `true`, so it probably makes sense. Nevertheless, I don't care about both `Value1` and `Value2` being `true` in this use case. I want to achieve that I have

- first all objects with `Value1` being true, within those ordered by
  `Value3`
- second all objects with `Value2` being true, within those
  ordered by `Value3`
- finally the rest, ordered by `Value3`

is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: everything is possible, trying to understand the question is proving to be a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value1).
    ThenByDescending(d => d.Value1 || d.Value2).
    ThenBy(d => d.Value3);
```

In the 2nd expression I use a combination of Value1 & Value2. If Value1 is `true` the result will always be `true` regardless of Value2 and thus 'skip' ordering the results. While if Value1 is `false` it'll depend solely on Value2.

Comment: This answer could have done with an explanation so that it's clear and concise.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt True. While it's quit straightforward I added a bit of explanation as to what it does.

Comment: Thank you, it just improves the quality of your answer and good answers like this deserve the additional effort.

Answer (score 2):

The below code may get you started. You have three rules, encoded in the first three lines of the code.

```
var firstBit = list.Where(z => z.Value1).OrderBy(z => z.Value3);
var secondBit = list.Where(z => !z.Value1 && z.Value2).OrderBy(z => z.Value3);
var last = list.Where(z => !z.Value1 && !z.Value2).OrderBy(z => z.Value3);

var final = firstBit.Concat(secondBit).Concat(last);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", final.Select(z => z.Value3)));
```

Comment: this btw also works - nevertheless @STDMP's solution is simpler for me

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below

Updated Code based on comment.

```
var orderedVal1 = list.Where(item=>item.Value1==true).OrderBy(d => d.Value3);
var orderedVal2 = list.Where(item=>item.Value1==false && item.Value2==true).OrderBy(d => d.Value3);
var orderedVal3 = list.Where(item=>item.Value1==false && item.Value2 ==false).OrderBy(d => d.Value3);

var orderedList = orederedval1.Concat(orderedVal2).Concat(orderedVal3);
```

Comment: Shouldn't we change orderedVal3 to check if BOTH value1 and value2 are false instead?

Comment: @Zulatin - Updated the code. Also, for orderedVal2 should only consider Value1 with false. Else will create duplicates for both val1 and val2 having true.

Comment: Using multiple lists and `Concat` is an awful way to do this.

Comment: as mjwills' answer also valid from a purely functional point of view